# List of places where new vote-button design hasn't been applied

Tags: bug, design, voting

[Four months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389359/1278220), we got a new vote-button design style. However, that new design hasn't been applied everywhere.
[Catija suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393595/the-established-user-help-page-image-should-be-updated#comment1316233_393595) that we do this to help out:

> While it'd be going the extra mile, if y'all happened to add other places that aren't user-editable where we're using screenshots of the old design, that'd be really helpful

This is intended to be more of a list of bug-reports associated with the change, rather than just a list of old screenshots.

(The original announcement post has more stuff about the design than about places where updating is needed.)

Answer (score 3):

List of issues:

- [The established-user help page image should be updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393595/the-established-user-help-page-image-should-be-updated) [(screenshot of issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi9X8.png)
- [Vote buttons in the election primary are different from the new vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393775/vote-buttons-in-the-election-primary-are-different-from-the-new-vote-buttons) [(screenshot of issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYLy3.png)
- [New vote-button font hasn't been applied everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390645/new-vote-button-font-hasnt-been-applied-everywhere)
- [Vote buttons in the tour page are different from the actual vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390088/vote-buttons-in-the-tour-page-are-different-from-the-actual-vote-buttons) [(screenshot of issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To7D3.png)
- [Vote buttons in the banner are different from the actual vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389859/vote-buttons-in-the-banner-are-different-from-the-actual-vote-buttons) [(screenshot of issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHnuf.jpg)